# Is there a shortcut in postman to comment a line?

Tags: postman

I am looking the Postman Shortcut panel but I don't see a shortcut to comment part of my code in a request body, it is very annoying to copy and paste `<!-- comment-->` to make a comment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the shortcut panel `Ctrl + /` open the shortcut panel but I accidentally did it in the request body and it comments the line

Comment: I think it depends on the keyboard layout. Just to complement the answer, in my layout worked with `Ctrl + ~`

Answer (score 8):

For the Body, raw category, you can use the following:

- Ctrl + k + c   (Will comment your selection)
- Ctrl + k + u   (Will un-comment your selection but also Uppercase
  everything)

I did not found other way to uncomment than deleting all the // bars by hand

I also found a nice work around on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bX4-cLPcD2Q

This was a Feature Request to the PostMan team. 21 days ago someone has added a comment asking exactly to revert a comment with Ctrl + K + U and also reporting the upper case issue. Let's hope they fix this soon.
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3358

**UPDATE**
The Post Team has fixed this issue so now you can use:

- Ctrl + k + c   (Will comment your selection)
- Ctrl + k + u   (Will un-comment your selection)

Even if the previous youtube trick is still valid, chances are it is not necessary anymore to create a pre-request script.

Comment: in what version is it fixed ?

Comment: This is just straight up lies, it is not fixed, granted the comment thread is very long and hard to follow but I am on latest and the behavior is still upper casing.

Comment: @TommyHolman this wasn't a lie, I personally tested one PostMan v8.3.0  where it was fixed!!    https://www.postman.com/downloads/release-notes

Suddenly at the next release, they stripped that back again. 
Do yourself a favour and ask them to fix it as my attempt just survive for one release!

Comment: You should Edit your answer so that future people coming here can see the whole story and know they accidentally broke it again.

Comment: This is uncommenting and also turning all letters to uppercase!

Comment: A workaround for the annoying uppercasing when you use Ctrl + K + U is to do Ctrl + H (replace command) then just replace all // with an empty string.

Comment: This is very frustrating. [Here is the open issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9114) if you want to track it and see if it is resolved in the future.  BUT, the issue does provide a different shortcut of Ctrl + / that does work (at least on windows 11 and postman version 9+!

Comment: @Morgeth888 Can someone **please** tell me in which scenario it is desired to removed comments making THE TEXT SHOUT at oneself? Any. Ever. Past, current and future. Including obscure and surrealistic. I'm so filled with unhappy thoughts right now...

Comment: @ToddB That issue will turn 3 years in a week... I don't feel the PostMan team takes that as a serious one. Which, ironically, is serious...

Answer (score 6):

I have tried in postman and the below worked form me.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> (Comments the line)
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (uncomments the line)

Comment: I can use [Ctrl]+[#] for both commenting and uncommenting lines without uppercasing.
I'm using v10.12.0  with a German keyboard.
[Ctrl]+[K]+[U] still results in uppercase.

Comment: For me [Ctrl]+[/] works for both commenting and uncommenting. Postman version: v10.15. [Ctrl]+[K]+[U] still results in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

As of Postman version 9.31.0, if you select multiple rows Postman still makes uppercase whilst uncommenting, with the key combination: ctrl + k + u

Workaround 1: ctrl + ö shortcut works well with my TR keyboard, it should be ctrl + . with the EN keyboard.

Workaround 2: That does not happen with single-line uncommenting, but you need to repeat it for each line (a bit annoying)

Answer (score 0):

Like it says above, if you add something like the below to your Pre-request Script tab, you can use either // or /* */ to comment out a line/section:

```
if(pm.request.body && pm.request.body.raw) pm.request.body.raw = pm.request.body.raw.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|\/\/.*/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

workaround

```
ctrl + k + c -> comment
ctrl + k + u -> uncomment and uppercase
ctrl + shift + u -> lowercase
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including ones that have been validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? (It seems very similar to other suggestions to me.) **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?